# I have to search a particular string and put a text and the end of the line containing that string using batch programming

Tags: string, search, batch-file

for e.g..
The Text file "sum.txt" contains following lines and I have to put text "ch" at the end of line containing string "param_code"

```
;JLP1
[parameters]
;pl_code
;param_code=a,b,c,d
[END]
```

I want a batch script to do this..Please help me out...Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not that easy with lines, that start with `;`

`findstr /n` adds line numbers, so the lines don't start with `;`

To strip the linenumbers, ignore token `1` (`%%i`) and use the rest (token `*`) (`%%i`).

Search for testpattern (`";param_code="`).

If found (`&&`), append additional text, if not found (`||`), write the original line to a new file.

overwrite the original file with the new file and delete the new file.

```
@echo off
del new.txt 2>nul
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" sum.txt') do (
 (echo(%%j|find ";param_code=" >nul) && echo(%%j,ch || echo(%%j
) >>new.txt
type new.txt >sum.txt
del new.txt
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, can't this be done without replacing the old file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a robust method:

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "sum.txt" |repl "(.*;param_code=)(.*)" "$1$2ch" > "sum-new.txt"
```